# finde countries of a grid R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I followed the following post to create a grid for hole africa:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396667/adequate-crs-when-creating-a-grid-over-a-whole-continent-in-r

Short version of the code:

```
africa <- gisco_get_countries(region = "Africa", resolution = 60, ) %>%
   st_union() %>%
    st_transform(3857)
africa <- africa %>% st_transform(32732)
grid <- st_make_grid(africa, cellsize = 55000) %>%
  st_intersection(africa) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>%
  st_sf() %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())
```

Now I want to find the country of each grid cell.
I tried the following:

```
remotes::install_github("constantin345/NOOA")
library(NOOA)
country <- st_centroid(grid)
country <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(country))
country$country <-coords2country(country$Y, country$X)
country$id <- 1:11445
```

With this code I have the problem, that if a centroid of a grid is not within the country (only next by), it gives me an NA - evethough parts of the grids are within an country.
So I would like to add the "next_by" country, if no country is found in the first attempt.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You could have more than one country with parts in a grid square when there's no country in the centre - how do you want to handle that? How about taking the grid centres and using `st_nearest` applied to the polygon map of countries?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to find countries behind each of grid's centroid, you can st_join the countries to grid centroids like:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

countries <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(region = "Africa", resolution = 60) |>
  st_transform(3857)

africa <- countries |>
  st_union()

grid <- st_make_grid(africa, cellsize = 55000) |>
  st_intersection(africa) |>
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") |>
  st_sf() |>
  dplyr::mutate(id = dplyr::row_number())
  
ggplot(africa) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = grid)
```

[image]

```r
grid |>
  st_centroid() |>
  st_join(countries)

#> Simple feature collection with 11559 features and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -7082216 ymin: -6364398 xmax: 8641122 ymax: 4457449
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
#> First 10 features:
#>    id CNTR_ID                                   CNTR_NAME ISO3_CODE
#> 1   1      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 2   2      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 3   3      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 4   4      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 5   5      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 6   6      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 7   7      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 8   8      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 9   9      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#> 10 10      TF Terres Australes Et Antarctiques Françaises       ATF
#>                              NAME_ENGL FID
#> 1  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 2  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 3  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 4  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 5  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 6  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 7  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 8  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 9  French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#> 10 French Southern and Antarctic Lands  TF
#>    st_cast.st_intersection.st_make_grid.africa..cellsize...55000...
#> 1                                          POINT (7677446 -6363400)
#> 2                                          POINT (7721245 -6362540)
#> 3                                          POINT (7776990 -6364398)
#> 4                                          POINT (7812834 -6363530)
#> 5                                          POINT (7676321 -6310926)
#> 6                                          POINT (7721419 -6311259)
#> 7                                          POINT (7774284 -6318672)
#> 8                                          POINT (7826684 -6316192)
#> 9                                          POINT (7680030 -6266698)
#> 10                                         POINT (7717085 -6267819)
```

in this data frame `id` that's `id` of grid.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think that helps - if you read the Q the problem is finding countries that intersect grid cells but **dont** cover the cell centroid, such as around the coast.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answer with the comments (Thanks!) the answer ist quite easy

```
countries <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(region = "Africa", resolution = 60) |>
  st_transform(3857)
join <- st_join(grid, countries, join = st_nearest_feature)
```